# php gmdate() Incorrect time zone

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

When I used:

```
echo gmdate("YmdHis O")
```

output is:

> 20151211091805 +0000

but is wrong in Italy now is 10:00, why is my error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [PHP: `gmdate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php):

> Identical to the date() function except that the time returned is **Greenwich Mean Time (GMT)**.

If you want local time, use [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 1):

set the timezone before getting the time

```
date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )
```

Then

```
 echo gmdate("YmdHis O");
```

Answer (score 0):

set time zone

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');